# Android API 22 permission model downgrade - Google Play Store new app version

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to upload the latest version of my application to Google Play Store, I see the following permission model downgrade error, even though I didn't change any project configurations.

**Error:**

```
Permission model downgrade

Problem:

Users that have the APK with version code 10605, which targets SDK 23 or higher, will receive an error when they attempt to upgrade to this APK because it targets SDK 22.

Resolution:

Ensure that your release includes APKs targeting SDK 23 or higher to which all users that have the APK with version code 10605 can upgrade.
```

I’ve tried setting the android-targetSdkVersion to 23 in config.xml and running cordova build android. Though the build was successful, the permissions of the application are broken.

What am I supposed to do to fix the above issue and also have my app permissions intact? Please let me know if you need any additional information.

**Config.xml**

[image: Config File Image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

[image: Android Manifest XML file]

Thank You

Comment: Can you include the `AndroidManifest.xml` found in the `platforms/android` folder in the cordova project?

Comment: Updated the `AndroidManifest.xml` file from my `platforms/android` @BShaps. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a `build.gradle` file somewhere in your projects that defines `targetSdkVersion`? AFAIK that setting will override anything specified in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Both of those look right, so to build off of what Michael said, there is likely a `.gradle` file that sets the target SDK version.  The most likely culprit is a plugin.  Probably the best plan of attack is to uninstall and reinstall the plugins if you aren't familiar with `.gradle` files.  Otherwise you can search your cordova directory for `*.gradle` and look through manually.  Don't just search for `build.gradle` because there are files such as `build-extras.gradle`

Comment: As suggested, I checked all the gradle files and also uninstalled the plugins and installed them with correct plugin version. Still I'm facing the same error. @BShaps